# URL String received to be entered into SQL Database

Tags: sql, csv, url

Ok this is totally new to me. I have a device that sends me a URL String to my static IP.

```
 /track.php?data=866224022900384,0,,S25 38.7066,E28 14.4893,0,1453.21,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Each section must be entered into a SQL database. The COMMAS is place holders for the SQL basically and can be filled. This looks like CSV values. How would be the best manner to execute this into a SQL database.

This is my first time working with data like this and have no idea where to start.

Comment: For a start: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?